# Что передается в параметре конструктора?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

не особо понимаю эту строку, какой тип данных передается в параметрах конструктора, понятно, что "map" строка, а что такое center и zoom и почему это в квадратных скобках не понятно P.s не понимаю, что мне нужно прочитать чтобы понять что тут написано

```
var myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {center: [59.943178, 30.415395], zoom: 12.5});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

new ymaps.Map("map", {center: [59.943178, 30.415395], zoom: 12.5});

1. "map" - строка;
2. {center: [59.943178, 30.415395], zoom: 12.5} - объект
3. center: [59.943178, 30.415395] - переменная объекта которая содержит массив
4. [59.943178, 30.415395] - массив
5. zoom: 12.5 - переменная объекта которая содержит число
6. 12.5 - число

Вы можете проверять тип методом typeof {center: [59.943178, 30.415395], zoom: 12.5} в консоли.

Comment: Только не бывает такого понятия **переменная объекта**. У объекта это либо **поле** либо **свойство**. В данном случае это **поле** объекта.

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko  писал простым языком что бы было понятно, спасибо за критику

Answer (score 0):

О смысле параметров zoom и center можно прочитать в документации:
https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/theory/index-docpage/

> Для того, чтобы с картой было удобно работать, вводится понятие коэффициента  (уровня) масштабирования. На нулевом уровне весь «мир» отображается на область размером 256х256 пикселей. При увеличении коэффициента масштабирования на единицу размеры «мира» увеличиваются ровно в 2 раза и, следовательно, для уровня масштабирования z составляют 2z+8x2z+8 пикселей.

Zoom это и есть коэффициент масштабирования.
Center - это гео-координата центра экрана.